# Ajax open() function : PHP process file path with an MVC structure

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm developing a site with an MVC architecture in PHP. I also use AJAX requests for some features but I have a problem with the path of the PHP processing file of these requests.

Here is my folder structure :

```
myProject
....public (root folder)
........index.php (app router)
........javascript
............ajaxScript.js

....src
........scripts
............ajaxProcessing.php
```

And my Javascript code :

```
var xhr = getXMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('POST', '../src/scripts/ajaxProcessing.php', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.send('token=' + token);
```

So to point to my PHP file, I am getting up two folders in the tree (to be in the `myProject` folder) and then down to `src/scripts/ajaxProcessing.php`. Note that the JS file `ajaxScript.js` is included in the router (`public/index.php`).

I tried lots of "logical" paths that could work but nothing works...
Can we go back in the tree for the Ajax query processing file? Does this come from the path I indicated?

nb: I tried to put the JS and PHP files in the same folder and it works, so it does not come from my Javascript or PHP script.

Comment: Where you’re getting twisted up is the way you’re trying to access the `ajaxProcessing` script. All requests, Ajax or not, go through your router (`index.php`). Your router then   manages the loading of your file, or better yet, hands off to your controller. You should never have to reference it the way you’re trying to do.

Comment: Ask yourself how are planning to access regular pages?  You’ll access ajax the same way.

Answer (score 0):

This is bad design by definition. Only PHP code should be able to access files that are above public folder.